# What does א.ד.ג.‏ stand for in Yiddish?

Tags: yiddish, acronyms

What does א.ד.ג.‏ stand for in Yiddish? It seems from context that it is the equivalent to etc. but I can't find what it stands for exactly.

For example, this this excerpt from a Hassidic story describing the Hassidim as having Yiddishe ways, and Jerusalemite dress with long caftans/kapputehs:

> אידישע צורות אנגעטען דעם ירושלמער לבוש, לאנגע קאפטענעס א.ד.ג

Comment: Can you give an example with context please?

Comment: excerpt from a Hassidic story: אידישע צורות אנגעטען דעם ירושלמער לבוש, לאנגע קאפטענעס א.ד.ג. Its describing the Hassidim as having Yiddishe ways, and Jerusalemite dress with long caftans/kapputehs.

Comment: If you could continue the sentence it might help

Answer (score 17, accepted):

און דאס גלייכן, which means "and similar." So yes, it's exactly equivalent to etc., 'וכו, et al.

Sometimes instead you find used .א.א.ז.וו, which stands for און אזוי ווייטער - and so forth.

Comment: Kind of like etc.